# Why can't download the web page into my target?

Tags: php

The code was saved as '/tmp/down.php' in my local pc.

```
<?php 
function downfile($fileurl)
    {
     ob_start(); 
     $filename=$fileurl;
     header( "Content-type:  application/octet-stream "); 
     header( "Accept-Ranges:  bytes "); 
     header( "Content-Disposition:  attachment;  filename= '/tmp/test'"); 
     $size=readfile($filename); 
     header( "Accept-Length: " .$size);
     }

$url="http://www.yahoo.com";
downfile($url);
?>
```

Why the yahoo web page was not saved as in /tmp/test,but displayed in the screen when to execute 'php /tmp/down.php'?

Comment: Is /tmp/ a public website?

Comment: no,it is a private directory in my local pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you did not save it to `/tmp/test`.  Try something like:

```
file_put_contents("/tmp/test", fopen("http://www.yahoo.com", 'r'));
```

Comment: i want to know why my code can not downlaod the web page into my target file but dispalyed in the terminal.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature  Because you are telling it to display it in the browser.  If you want to save it as your target file, you must tell it to save it as your target file using `file_put_content()` or some similar function.